# Pre-defined search queries stored local php, mysql efficiency

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been unable to find a solution probably because I get so many partial results searching for my question.

I have a mysql database being frequently searched for a specific string or strings which define the usage of a chat room.

I do not need a custom search and I can generalizea list to 30-50 items that will encompass every term that I need searched.

Would it be more efficient for me to simply load this 30-50 item list with numbers associated when the website is loaded and store integers in the database.

Example:
string1
string2

Rather than querying for string1 in the database chat rooms, I would just query for 1 knowing it corresponds to string1 in my txt file.

Is this more efficient and what is the best way to preload this list of queried phrases into an html/php session.

Thanks.

Comment: unless the searches are effecting the site in some way, i wouldn't bother. mysql with be caching the common ones anyway

Comment: i am not sure why you are so reluctant using mysql, querying database is much more efficient then to use text file(io).